# setting up pgadmin4 on a VPS running ubuntu. Configuring it from nginx

Tags: django, linux, nginx, gunicorn, pgadmin-4

The final instructions for configuring nginx for pgadmin4 read:

```
location / {
        proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/pgadmin4.sock;
        include proxy_params;
    }
```

but I already had that proxy_pass configured for this:

```
location @proxy_to_app {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://app_server; <----HERE
    }
```

the app_server refers to:

```
upstream app_server {  
  server unix:/home/boards/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
```

so, the proxy_pass is sort-of already taken. The instructions come from digitalocean

UPDATE:
I had already tried adding this, which I know it is correct:

```
location / {
        proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/pgadmin4.sock;
        include proxy_params;
    }
```

but there is one more thing to do for nginx to communicate with gunicorn, otherwise it will give me the 502 bad gateway error, namely:

```
gunicorn --bind unix:/tmp/pgadmin4.sock --workers=13 --threads=25 --chdir ~/environments/my_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pgadmin pgAdmin:app
```

I will create a separate question in another post in order to honor the answer given, but the issue is still unresolved as there is this extra binding address to be done. l

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up a separate location block in your `Nginx` configuration for `pgAdmin4` because you already have a `proxy_pass` directive pointing to another application.

To avoid conflicts, you can set up `pgAdmin4` under a different URI if you want to access pgAdmin4 via your domain like `yourdomain.com/pgadmin` like below:

```
location /pgadmin/ {
    proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/pgadmin4.sock;
    include proxy_params;
}
```

*Make sure to adjust the URI `/pgadmin/` as per your preference.*

After making this change you need to restart your nginx server. But before restarting it's a good practice to test the configuration for any syntax errors `sudo nginx -t`

```
sudo nginx -t    
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Now, For testing open your web browser and check if the URL you set is working with pgadmin (e.g., yourdomain.com/pgadmin)

Note: If you don't have domain setup in your Nginx server you can try with your IP address (e.g., yourServerIP/pgadmin)

Comment: Thank you. I did try that yesterday but I got a: 502 Bad Gateway
nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)  This only happens when I try to reach that url www.myweb.com/pgadmin  it does not happen with www.myweb.com A bad gateway 502, in my understanding, happens when nginx is not communicating with gunicorn, but like I said, it only happens with that extra url, the www.myweb.com/pgadmin

Comment: There is still one pending instruction: gunicorn --bind unix:/tmp/pgadmin4.sock --workers=1 --threads=25 --chdir ~/environments/my_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pgadmin4 pgAdmin4:app  and this is key I think: Currently my web is running thanks to supervisor keeping my gunicorn bash file alive, so I don't know what I have to do with this sentence if gunicorn is already running. Somehow I have to add it.